# How to sequentially start activities across different Android modules in Kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl, android-multi-module

I have an Android project with two modules, let's call them Module A and Module B. In Module A, I have two activities, A and B. In Module B, I have an activity named X. I'm trying to achieve a sequential flow where I start Activity X from Activity A and then start Activity B from Activity X.

whenever i am trying to do so using intent or using navigator interface,i am getting circular dependency error.

Comment: You cannot have Module A depend on Module B and have Module B depend on Module A. Most likely, you will need this navigation logic to reside somewhere else, such as in an app module that depends on both Module A and Module B.

Comment: @CommonsWare Could you please provide some example to achieve that